# What would cause an LWC @wire callout to fail?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I am building a Lightning Web Component that should create a click-configurable datatable that can be put on Lightning pages and show content in a variety of ways. To both build the table and retrieve the data for it, I have a `@wire` callout to my Apex controller.

```
@wire( queryInfo, {
        recordId        : "$recordId",
        childLookup     : "$childLookup",
        filter          : "$filter",
        fsApi           : "$fsApi",
        isRelatedList   : "$isRelatedList",
        objApi          : "$objApi"
} ) wiredQueryInfo(value) {
    this.queryInfoResults = value;
    if ( value.error ) {
        this.setAlert( {
            "class" : errorAlertClass,
            "icon"  : errorAlertIcon,
            "msg"   : "Server side error, could not load list. Error logged to console.",
            "type"  : "error",
            "var"   : "inverse"
        } );
        console.error( "ERROR: fieldSetDatatable.wiredQueryInfo .. " + value.error );
    } else if ( value.data ) {
        this.cols = value.data.cols;
        this.fsLabel = value.data.fsLabel
        this.rows = value.data.rows;
    }
    this.showSpinner = false;
}
```

This callout never appears to fire, though. I enter the wired function, but both the error and data variables on `value` are null. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: can you provide your apex code so we can take a look. Also, are you seeing an errors in the js console in chrome or in the developer console in SF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wire service will initially be invoked while the Lightning framework registers the service - you will get both `data` and `error` to be `undefined` at this point - it does not really depend on the parameters you are passing. Next time, it will be invoked ONLY when none of the parameters being passed are undefined.

Check if all the parameters have values:

```
{
        recordId        : "$recordId",
        childLookup     : "$childLookup",
        filter          : "$filter",
        fsApi           : "$fsApi",
        isRelatedList   : "$isRelatedList",
        objApi          : "$objApi"
}
```

Improvement suggestion:

Put above parameters in a parameter and fetch it in apex. Sample as below:

JS:

```
@wire(queryInfo, {
    params: '$params'
})
wiredQueryInfo(value) {
    // logic for value.data/value.error
}

connectedCallback() {
    this.params = {
        recordId: this.recordId,
        childLookup: this.childLookup,
        // other params
    };
}
```

and APEX:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Map<String, Object> queryInfo(Map<String, Object> params) {
    String recordId = params.containsKey('recordId') ? (String)params.get('recordId') : null;
    Integer childLookup = params.containsKey('childLookup') ? Integer.valueOf(params.get('childLookup')) : 0;
    // fetch other params
}
```

Advantage with this is, you can invoke `queryInfo` with passing only needed - and omitting unneeded parameters. It will always invoke it because `params` will never be undefined. However, you have to take care that you properly set the value of `params` and use `debug` statements in apex for initially understanding the transactions.

Comment: That worked, thanks! For clarification sake, I thought that, in JavaScript, an undefined variable meant one that had not been declared earlier in scope. Is that not correct?

Comment: Even if you declare without assigning a value, then it will be `undefined`. It is useful only to make it tracked or api enabled