# LWC @wire method is not being called

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript

I have @wire method in LWC which has one parameter as account id and displays all the related contacts . I am calling this LWC from aura component which is working fine . I have other scenario where I want to display all the contacts (not respective with account) . So I put my lwc componet in lightning page and exposed as tab but i am not able to get the records to de displayed the table was empty

```
aura :


<aura:attribute name="accId" type="Id"/>
  <c:contactdetails accId="{!v.accId}"></c:contactdetails>
```

LWC :

```
@api accId; 
@track conData = [];

@wire(getContacts, {accId: '$accId'}) accList(result) {

    if (result.data) {
        let conList = [];
        result.data.forEach((conVal) => {
            let con = {};
            con.Id =  conVal.Id;
            con.Name =  conVal.Name;
            con.conRecord = '/' + conVal.Id;
            con.quantity = conVal.quantity__c;
        }
        conList.push(oli);
        });
        this.conData = conList;
    
    } else if (result.error) {

        this.error = result.error;
        alert(this.error);
    
    }
}
```

apex :

```
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable = true)
    public static List<Contact> getContacts(Id accId){
        system.debug('accId>>>>>>'+accId);        
        if(accId!=null){
            return [SELECT id,Name,quantity__c from Contact where AccountId =:accId];
        }else{
            return [SELECT id,Name,quantity__c,Contractor__c from Contact where Contractor__c=:UserInfo.getUserId()];
        }
    }
```

I am not even getting logs when the account id is empty

Comment: The parameter is `conId`, but you're trying to pass in `accId`. Make sure you're looking at the right code, and passing in the correct values.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have updated my question . When i call the lwc from aura component it works .I mean when i pass the accId it works  . but when i expose this lwc in lightning page .. i dont get any records. It not entering the apex method also

Comment: Can you share the code for Parent Component.

Comment: Extending the above comment, please include the parent's template and JS. Just [edit] your question to add it. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming this LWC is standalone on the Lightning page you reference - are you expecting to set accId through the component's UI options, or are you trying to get it from a lightning record page?  Have a look at this documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_record_context

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275820/what-would-cause-an-lwc-wire-callout-to-fail This had resolved my issue .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would cause an LWC @wire callout to fail?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275820/what-would-cause-an-lwc-wire-callout-to-fail)